# Gradio Client Streaming

Tags: python-3.x

I am using gradio client in python to get data from a space, the space is running Falcon 40B.
My issue is that it seems to only wait until the space has processed the first token, and I've tried this on multiple chatbots, so it's an issue with my code.

Here is my code:

```
from gradio_client import Client
import time

instructions="""The following is a conversation between a highly knowledgeable and intelligent AI assistant, called Falcon, and a human user, called User. In the following interactions, User and Falcon will converse in natural language, and Falcon will answer User's questions. Falcon was built to be respectful, polite and inclusive. Falcon was built by the Technology Innovation Institute in Abu Dhabi. Falcon will never decline to answer a question, and always attempts to give an answer that User would be satisfied with. It knows a lot, and always tells the truth. The conversation begins."""

client = Client("https://huggingfaceh4-falcon-chat.hf.space/",serialize=False)
response = client.submit(
                "Hey There! Respond to this with I like chicken.",  # str  in 'Type an input and press Enter' Textbox component
                [], # str (filepath to JSON file) in 'parameter_9' Chatbot component
                instructions,   # str  in 'Instructions' Textbox component
                0.8,    # int | float (numeric value between 0.1 and 2.0) in 'Temperature' Slider component
                0.6,    # int | float (numeric value between 0.1 and 0.99) in 'p (nucleus sampling)' Slider component
                fn_index=1
)



print(response.result())
```

This returns

```
[['Hey There! Respond to this with I like chicken.', 'I']]
```

I have tried using submit and response, and I have tried predict as well. Nothing changes it.